# How to delete an image from sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How can I delete an image file from sd card. I have tried:

```
File file=new File(filepath);  
file.delete();
```

but I could not delete it. when I try to inspect it in debug mode, file.delete() is returning false. 
I have also added permission in my Manifest file.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

I also tried with:

```
public abstract boolean deleteFile (String name)
```

method from andoid context. Even that returns false.

Comment: That should work... can you post an example of what you're passing in for filepath? Also: you're sure the sd card isn't mounted for external USB storage when you're trying this, right?

Comment: /sdcard/myDir/myPicName.jpg this is the file path iam passing. I hav also tried with /mnt/sdcard/myDir/myPicName.jpg but it doesnt work

Comment: myDir is the temporary folder that i hav created.

Comment: in fact i hav saved that file to attach as an attachment to the mail. So, after sending mail, i want to delete it.

Comment: Does Android find the file? Does exists() return true?

Comment: Android is finding the file as its sending correctly to email as an attachment

Comment: @TiBo yes, i hav checked file.exists(). it does return true. but file.delete() is returning false

Comment: You can use getExternalCacheDir() if ur device api level is above 8. You can save your image there. It will be automatically deleted when you uninstall the app and also no need of creating any sample directories

Comment: How did you create the temporary dir? if you created externally from your app, then your app may not have permissions on it (even the WRITE_EXTERNAL will not be enough)

Comment: ' root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
       + File.separator + "bistro_temp" + File.separator);
     root.mkdirs();
     sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "coupon.png");'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing static value for sd-card storage directory, it would be better to use
[getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to retrieve exact value of sd-card directory. (Because it may be /sdcard or /mnt/sdcard so):

```
String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

Detailed example is here: [Check and Gets the Android external storage directory](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/04/check-and-gets-android-external-storage.html)